# SQLITE database Manipulating error with java (IDE:Netbeans)

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite, netbeans-7

I am facing a problem with Sqlite database in java IDE NetBeans.

I have four tables in my database and 3 tables of them working properly but last one table is not working! Suppose when I want to insert my data in `JTable` and Database it shows the values in `JTable` **but sometimes it inserts and sometimes it does not insert values into database!**

Below is the action performed on button through which data is inserted into jTable and database!

```
private void jButton17ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String sql = "insert into month (No,Description,Sale,Expense,Total)
                      values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txt_srM.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txt_dateM.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txt_tsaleM.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txt_texpM.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txt_subtM.getText());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the exception message say when it fails?

Comment: It does not show any message! Sometimes it inserts data into jTable and Database and sometimes it inserts data only into jTable but not into database!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Connect your database in your first statement. i.e.

```
  con = (YourDB/urDBconnectingClassName)
  try {
    String sql = "insert into month (No,Description,Sale,Expense,Total)
                  values (?,?,?,?,?)";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txt_srM.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txt_dateM.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txt_tsaleM.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txt_texpM.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txt_subtM.getText());
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

and if you are doing so..
then you must be closing your DB connection in end of method, i.e.

```
 }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
    try{
        rs.close();  //where rs = resultstatement
        pst.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

if u dont close connection and it is connecting in another method.. you might get error of DATABASE Lock! error..

Hope this will help you!